# Cannot open Scene Builder 8.2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, scenebuilder, eclipse-mars

I am trying to install Scene Builder 8.2.0 and use it to Eclipse Mars.
I've visited the site http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/ and downloaded the x64 version as advised. When I run the .exe file it seems that the installation is successfully completed.

But the thing is that when I go to the place where the Scene Builder folder is supposed to be appeared (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local`) it doesn't exist. I tried the other version (x86) with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The site you have given is for the gluon version of scene builder for the correct version of scene builder visit oracles site. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html#javafx-scenebuilder-2.0-oth-JPR

Comment: I am not sure but i think that oracle doesn't develop Scene Builder anymore. But if you can help me with a link that would have been really great.

Comment: They don't however there is a working version (scene builder 2.0) that is great to use on there website. It is the one I use personally.

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again but I've visited oracle's site and I can't find where i can download Scene Builder. If you can post a link that would be really really helpful.

Comment: @ZZZ not a problem the link is in the answer